# \Cite vs. \cite

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

In LaTeX both the `\cite` and `\Cite` commands work and for me (using `biblatex`) and produce the same output.

What is the difference between the capitalized and non-capitalized version of `\cite`, `\citauthor` et.al.?

Comment: "\Cite is similar to \cite but capitalizes the name prefix of the first name in the citation if the useprefix option is enabled, provided that there is a name prefix and the citation style prints any name at all." Quote from the biblatex documentation. For `\citeauthor` its the same

Comment: @samcarter Please turn that comment into an answer, maybe with an example that shows the difference (e.g. "ibid" styles where `\cite` produces "ibid." and `\Cite` "Ibid." and names with a prefix and `useprefix=true` where `\cite` produces "van Gennep" and `\Cite` "Van Gennep" (`vangennep` in `biblatex-examples.bib`).)

Comment: @moewe Done! Thanks a lot for all the examples you suggested!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The difference between `\cite` and `\Cite` is the capitalization.

`\Cite` should make sure that the citation starts with an uppercase letter and is thus appropriate for the beginning of a sentence. Note that `biblatex` can only capitalise those contents of `\cite`/`\Cite` that it has control over and that `biblatex` is fairly conservative in its application of capitalisation macros. That means that in practice only bibstrings and name prefixes ('von', 'van', ... etc.) are capitalised automatically.

Most of the time you won't see a difference because names are normally already capitalised, but if your name has a prefix, like 'van' in the example below, you'll see the difference.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}

\cite{vangennep}

\Cite{vangennep}

\end{document}
```

[image: "van Gennep 1909" and "Van Gennep 1909"]

Another case where this becomes relevant are styles that replace consecutive citations of the same work with 'ibid':

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authoryear-ibid]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}

\cite{vangennep}

\cite{vangennep}

\Cite{vangennep}

\end{document}
```

[image: "van Gennep 1909", "ibid." and "Ibid."]